# Python unittest separate setup() method for each test

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am bit confused about the usage of `setUp` method in unittest

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)

> setUp()
>
> Method called to prepare the test fixture. This is called immediately before calling the test method; other than AssertionError or SkipTest, any exception raised by this method will be considered an error rather than a test failure. The default implementation does nothing.

Now I understand that `setUp` would be called before each testcase from the testsuite.

But if each of the testcase needs to do something else in their respective `setUp` and `tearDown`, how can I do that in these methods. It seems they are generic for each of the testcases

Since each of the testcase is for the same feature so logically they belong to the same testsuite. I can easily write the setup and teardown steps in the test method itself, but then `setUp` and `tearDown` would lose its purpose

Comment: Those methods are useful if you have operations to run before or after every tests, like open and close a file. You could also duplicate these operations right inside your tests, but that would be ugly.

Comment: Yes, but I may need to open/close different files before each of the testcases, right ? The same `setUp/tearDown` will not help

Comment: In this case you do this inside your tests.

Comment: Uggh !! That is exactly what I wish to avoid ;) in my original question

Comment: I understand, but it's better to add extra lines than to build something that would be too much complex...

Comment: The purpose of setUp and tearDown is to run *common code* before/after each tests within your class (eg open a connection to a database, or read some test data). Perhaps you can abstract out your setup/teardown requirements into different classes such that you keep it DRY, eg: one test class opens/closes one file. If this doesn't work for your requirements I'd suggest a helper function that you can call from within the test - that will improve both readability and reusability.

Comment: You won't be able to achieve test-specific setup with `unittest`, it's pretty limited. The only possibility coming to mind is to move each test that requires specific setup to a separate `TestCase` class. Ever thought about the change of test framework? Both `nose` and `pytest` have easy constructs (`with_setup` decorator in `nose`/fixtures in `pytest`) for test-specific setup and teardown.

Comment: Aside from that, you can customize the code in `setUp`/`tearDown` by test name: `if self._testMethodName == 'testFeatureOne': ... elif self._testMethodName == 'testFeatureTwo': ...` etc, but it is ugly and can't compete with the excellent `pytest` fixtures IMO.

Comment: And last but not least - what you are trying to do (separating the setup, teardown and the actual test) is the right thing to do; putting setup/teardown code in tests is a bad idea. A test should only fail from an assertion, not from the test preparation or the afterwards cleanup.

Comment: "`setUp` would be called before each testcase from the testsuite." No, it will be called before each test in the `TestCase`.