# Defining pytest fixtures in a standalone class

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I started with another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793857/python-unittest-separate-setup-method-for-each-test?noredirect=1#comment100235673_56793857) where it was suggested to use `fixtures` in `pytest`

I am trying to figure out if `fixtures` can reside in a standalone class. The examples over the net have them as standalone functions or inherited from another class

**My usecase**

Why I need them to be standalone ?

I have a class which would connect to external directory server(like LDAP). This class would have `fixtures` to create/delete objects in the directory server.

Multiple LDAP test classes should be able to use the `ExternalDirectory` class and connect to different LDAP directory servers

```
- external_server.py

import ldap
import pytest

class ExternalDirectory(object):
  def __init__(self, creds):
    self.connection = #connect to LDAP server

  @pytest.fixture
  def create_user(self):
    user = []
    def _create_user(self, user_name):
      #create user in ldap
      user.append(user_name)

    yield _create_user
    #delete user list

  #More fixtures of such kind

  def utility_method1(self):
    # some util method

  #More such util methods
```

The test class will use this class

```
- test_ldap_users.py

import ExternalDirectory

class TestLdapUser(object):
  @classmethod
  def setup_class(cls):
    #Fetch credentials from some YAML
    cls.ldap_connection = ExternalDirectory(creds)

  def test_ldap_user_create(self, <need-to-call-create-user-fixture-here>):
    create_user('some-user-name')
    ...
```

**The Issue**

But I am unable to call the fixture here in the testcase. Infact, I can't figure out how to even call them :)

**Alternate approach**

To inherit the `ExternalDirectory` class. But then I'll need to remove `__init__` and move it to `setup_class` for `ExternalDirectory`, then call `setup_class` in `TestLdapUser`.

**Limitation in the alternate approach**

The `connection` attribute created in `setup_class` method of `ExternalDirectory` will not be exclusive for each of the LDAP test class

**Question**

What would be a good way to handle this ?

Comment: @hoefling I had a chat about pytest, with you, under this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56793857/python-unittest-separate-setup-method-for-each-test and now I am stuck with this requirement. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach I am using currently, but I don't like it

```
class LDAPFixtures(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls, init_data):
        cls.connection = LDAPConnectionInit(init_data)      

    @pytest.fixture
    def create_and_delete_ou(self):
        ou_list = []

        def _create_organizational_unit(ou_name):

            # Code to create an OU
            ou_list.append(ou_name)

            yield _create_organization_unit

            # Code to delete OU

class TestLDAPConnections(LDAPFixtures):
    def test_ou_1(self, create_and_delete_ou):
      # Do something
      ...

      # Now call the fixture
      create_and_delete_ou(random_ou_name)

      # Continue to do something and conclude the test
```

**Why I don't like it ??**

I need to create multiple LDAP objects to different servers, so I wish to implement the `__init__`, create multiple objects for each LDAP connection, then call the fixtures from that object.

So, instead of inheritance I need composition relation. So something like this would be cool

```
class TestServer():
   @classmethod
   def setup_class(cls):
       cls.ldap1 = LDAPConnection()

   def test_LDAP1(self):
       # Some operations
       ...

       # Call fixture
       cls.ldap1.create_n_delete_user()

       # Continue and conclude the test

class LDAPConnection(LDAPFixtures):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ldap_conn = # some LDAP initialization

    def create_n_delete_user(self):
        # Some way to invoke fixture, give the control
        # back to testcase to continue, then back to fixture
        # after yield, for cleanup

class LDAPFixtures():
    @pytest.fixture
    def _create_and_delete_user(self):
        # Create user

        yield

        # Delete user
```